# Text to Speech in opencv

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, text-to-speech

I am working on a project where I need to process obstacles form the video feed of a room, and use that to give navigation directions to a blind person over wireless headphones, so that he can move around the room. I can't figure out a way to convert a given string(like " turn left and go straight 5 steps") to speech.

> Please suggest me a way to do this.I am new to computer vision, so any help would be appreciated. Isn't there a function like putText to get a string into speech? I am using the C API in visual studio 2010.
>   Thanx in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with computer vision or OpenCV. You need a text-to-speech engine.

Comment: I looked up SAPI for creating speech apps in vs10. But I need speech and Image Processing in the same Application in real time. 
Maybe I will prepare Video files with only speech and use those for now.

Comment: @user3181009 You need to find something that deals with voice in addition to image processing engine, . It does not make sense to prepare video files with voice, just to play voice

Comment: Process the images to do whatever to create text directions. Then feed the text to SAPI to get speech. Or if you have a fixed set of directions like "Stop", "Quarter turn left" you could just play recordings.

Comment: SAPI can speak in real time.  It's more than adequate for your project.